# Swap items in a doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am studying for my Algorithms exam and I have an exercise where I need to swap two items of a doubly linked list if a condition is true. (Language: C)
More specifically, I have a list of this kind:

```
H <-> |prev|Frequency1|VALUE1|next| <-> |prev|Frequency2|VALUE2|next| <-> ... <-> NULL
```

The frequency field increases every time I search for the relative value. The list must be ordered according to the frequency (in decreasing order, so at the very top there is the most searched item)

The problem is, I am not very good in exchanging pointers, I tried many times to do it but I have no clue. I guess that the problem I am facing is that I don't know how to use a temp item to keep track of what I am doing without loosing data.

I think that the case I have to consider are:

- First item of the list
- Last item of the list
- Item is in the middle of the list.

My attempt, certainly wrong is:

```
int Search(int x, list* head) {

    int contapos = 0;
    list* i;
    list* aus;

    for (i=head; i!=NULL; i = i->next, contapos++)
    {

        if (i->key == x)
        {
            i->freq++; // Increase frequency

            aus = i->prev;

            while ((i->freq > aus->freq))
            { // Keep ordered the frequencies

                if (i->next != NULL)
                {
                    i->next->prev = aus;
                }

                if (aus->prev != NULL)
                {
                    aus->prev->next = i;
                }

                aus->next = i->next;
                i->prev = aus->prev;
                aus->prev = i;
                i->next = aus;

            }

            /* Return counter */
            return contapos;

        }

    }

    return -1; // In case the item i am searching is not there
}
```

Thank you in advance for everything!

**Edit:**
as requested, I am adding the main (and the whole code just to be sure) of the program at the moment

```
typedef struct _list {
int key;
int freq;
struct _list *next;
struct _list *prev;
} list;

list* head;
list* tail;

void swap(list *lhs, list *rhs) {
list *temp;

temp = lhs->prev;
lhs->prev = rhs->prev;
rhs->prev = temp;

temp = lhs->next;
lhs->next = rhs->next;
rhs->next = temp;
}


void InsertAtTail(int value) {
list *newNode;
newNode = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
newNode->key = value;

if(head == NULL)
{
    head = newNode;
}
else
{
    tail->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = tail;
}

tail = newNode;
tail->next = NULL;
}

int SearchAndIncrement(int x, list** head) {
int contapos = 0;
list* i;

// Let's find the element with the matching key
for (i = *head; i != NULL; i = i->next, contapos++)
    if (i->key == x)
        break;

// If we did not find the node, return -1 to denote failure.
if (i == NULL)
    return -1;

// Increase frequency
i->freq++;

// Move this node forward while the frequency is not in the correct position.
while (i->next && i->prev && (i->freq > i->prev->freq))
    swap(i, i->prev);

// The head might have been moved.
while ((*head)->prev != NULL)
    (*head) = (*head)->prev;

// Return the original position
return contapos;
}


int main () {

int N;
scanf("%d", &N);

head = NULL;
tail = NULL;

int i, value;
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &value);
    InsertAtTail(value);
}

/* Initializing frequencies */
list* aus;
for (aus=head; aus; aus = aus ->next) {
    aus->freq = 0;
}

int x, pos;
do {
    scanf("%d", &x);
    pos = SearchAndIncrement(x, &head);
    printf("%d ", pos);
    printf("[");
    aus = head;
    while (aus!=NULL) {
        printf("%d ", aus->key);
        aus = aus->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");

} while (pos != -1);

return 0;


}
```

Comment: I'm a little worried that the while condition does not change, even after you (correctly?) switch the pointers.  Does it get stuck?

Comment: I print the list every time to see what is actually happening and basically what happens is that the item i search disappears, then I search some other item and it appears again!

I can post the whole code if it is helpful, basically in the main I have a while that only stops when I have a -1 and it changes the positions of the items every time I do a new search, ordering them according to their frequencies.

Comment: Assuming this is *not* a circular list (and the picture makes that seem a safe leap), I see one issue immediately. If the item you're incrementing is at the *head* of a list of more than one item, the code invokes undefined behavior. Hint: what is the value of `aus` when `i` references the head of the list, and what value do you expect from `aus->freq` in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's simplify the problem. The complicated pointer portion is when we are trying to move a node forward in the list. So let's create some functions just for that.

```
void RemoveNode(list *node) {
    if (node->prev)
        node->prev->next = node->next;
    if (node->next)
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
}

void InsertNodeBetween(list *lhs, list *node, list *rhs) {
    if (lhs) assert(lhs->next == rhs);
    if (rhs) assert(rhs->prev == lhs);

    if (lhs) lhs->next = node;
    if (rhs) rhs->prev = node;

    node->prev = lhs;
    node->next = rhs;
}
```

Once we've done that, then we can more easily talk about the operation that you want to do.

```
int SearchAndIncrement(int x, list** head) {
    int contapos = 0;
    list* i;

    // Let's find the element with the matching key
    for (i = *head; i != NULL; i = i->next, contapos++)
        if (i->key == x)
            break;

    // If we did not find the node, return -1 to denote failure.
    if (i == NULL)
        return -1;

    // Increase frequency
    i->freq++;

    // Move this node forward while the frequency is not in the correct position.
    while (i->next && (i->freq > i->next->freq)) {
        list *prev = i->next;
        list *next = i->next->next;
        RemoveNode(i);
        InsertNodeBetween(prev, i, next);
    }

    // The head might have been moved.
    while ((*head)->prev != NULL)
        (*head) = (*head)->prev;

    // Return the original position
    return contapos;
}
```

### Some commentary:

The important thing to note here is that we have the ability to create **multiple functions**. And we can use those functions to make the amount of the problem that we need to keep in our head at any one time smaller.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I am sorry if my english isn't very reach in its syntax, so I might do some mistakes.

I forgot to mention that something that might be useful is that the nodes that we need to swap are always consecutive (because this function should keep it ordered), moreover I don't know if this is of any use but the data of the list is ordered too in the test sets. 

What you are suggesting is to create a search function to insert in the function that increments the frequency and keeps them ordered? I don't understand if your lhs and rhs are consecutive

Comment: +1 for not just debugging OP's code but giving advice how to design things to make life easier. Also spotted a typo: `if(i == null)` should be `NULL`, I think.

Comment: @user3790865: The `swap()` function is implemented in such a way that it does not require that the elements are neighbors, but it will work fine if they are.

Comment: @user3790865: I was able to infer that the initial dataset was sorted. Otherwise, the problem statement would not make sense.

Comment: I am trying to understand the code right now, sorry if I am a bit slow but this is the first time I swap pointers in doubly linked lists. Why in the Next steps you used 3 arguments in the SearchandIncrement functions? By the way you were right assuming that     contapos is returning the value of the position of the element I am searching.

Comment: @user3790865: I've added some additional commentary that you might find helpful.

Comment: @sharth I am trying the SearchandIncrement() but it doesn't swap any item, besides, as you stated, if I search the first value:
Example:
List of 3 values: [1 2 3] 
SearchAndIncrement(1,head)
Returns:
0 [1 ]

So the position is correct, but it looses the other nodes

Comment: @user3790865: I believe that the commentary I've added would cover this. Note that if you were to call `SearchAndIncrement(2, head)` the code above as given will work fine. The only reason that `SearchAndIncrement(1, head)` fails is because it is operating on the head of the list. So after calling it, `head->prev` points to __3__. and `head->prev->prev` points to __2__.

Comment: @sharth How does it point to 3? It is not circular. By the way, I tried to draw an example list on paper, and I tried the swap code. Thing is, it seems to swap the values, but the item before the two items that are being swapped has no reference to the next one, am I right? Indeed, I also tried it on the PC and even if I search a value in the middle (the 2) it looses the third value

Comment: @user3790865: Oops. There's a bug in my swap code. I've changed the last line of `swap()`.

Comment: @sharth To be honest, I don't know what's happening, if I use the code, with the corrected swap function it doesn't swap, but at least it doesn't loose any element of the list. 
Thing is, at a certain point it DOES loose an element, and if I search for the first element it doesn't print the list anymore giving me: 99% cpu and a very high energy and memory impact. 

Should I try to put the first-last node conditions in the swap function?


PS:the condition shouldn't be this?
while (i->next && i->freq < i->prev->freq)

Comment: Can you add a main() to the post and I'll take a look if I missed anything else.

Comment: @sharth I just edited the main post, thank you!P.s. I tried to change the while condition, but I only get segfault

Comment: @Roberto: Yeah, my `swap()` function is trash... I'm not sure what I was thinking. One mintue.

Comment: The code I've posted should actually work now: http://ideone.com/HM8vAP Sorry for the mess on the way to this result.

Comment: @sharth Thank you, now it does move the elements, not in the way I wanted to, though -  but in the opposite. I am now trying to fix that by myself :) 
I wanted to ask you: I never used the assert, is that necessary? If so, I am going to read something about them :)

Comment: @sharth sorry for the further stupid question, why you removed the function swap and you used the Remove and Insertbetween functions? What was the problem with a function like the swap one?

Comment: @Roberto: If we swap neighbors like I was doing, then afterwords: `lhs->next == lhs`. Which is terrible. The asserts are simply contracts that the function is supposed to have. They simply cause the program to error out at that line if the condition is not held. They are a useful way to make sure that your code is sane, which is what I was using them for.

Comment: @sharth I was just trying to do that change I told you before (the list item should move backwards and not forward) and I always get a SEG. Fault, why in your opinion?
      if (i->prev!= NULL) {
    while ((i->freq > i->prev->freq)) {
        list *prev = i->prev->prev;
        list *next = i->prev;
        RemoveNode(i);
        InsertNodeBetween(prev, i, next);
    }
    }

EDIT: Sorry, it wasn't supposed to paste in this way! How can I paste it like a code?

Comment: @Roberto: By backwards, do you mean that the elements with the largest frequency should be at the front of the list? That is, closer to the head?

Comment: @sharth I don't know if I am doing something wrong, but I should consider the two items before the element. The error is given at the while condition, but perhaps the problem is that a certain node doesn't have two elements backwards?

Comment: @sharth Yes sorry, I hadn't seen your reply. The frequencies should be decreasing. As you said, the more an element is searched, the closer it is to the head

Comment: @shart That removes the elements i am searching. 
Correction after some tests: It removes the element i am searching if it's frequency is larger than the previous

Comment: @Roberto: I can't recreate that problem: https://gist.github.com/sharth/03f54d06bc2cf1b4e612 What input are you using?

Comment: @sharth I never have been good at coding, so I guess a day is not a big problem :) The input is:
3 // Size of list
1
2
3
3 Output: 2 [1-2 - ]
2 Output: 1 [1 - ]
1 Output: 0 [list remains 1 and frequencies are increased]

Comment: With the code posted in that gist, I'm not able to recreate that: https://gist.github.com/sharth/03f54d06bc2cf1b4e612#comment-1255165

Comment: @sharth Ugh, I am sorry it is my fault! I changed the Insert function in this way: http://pastebin.com/TBb8VtHv thinking it was the same, but apparently it isn't! Now everything works, thank you for your time, really! You were of great help to me, sorry if I kept this thread too long!